# How to read in a key in .bashrc containing "$" from Python?

Tags: python, bash

I am using `os.environ['my_key']` to read in a key from my `.bashrc`. For example, if `my_key="123$abc"` were in `.bashrc` then `os.environ['my_key']` would return `123bc`.

Is there a trick to read in the full key?

Comment: If you have the string `my_key="123$abc"` in your .bashrc, that will set `my_key` to the string `123` concatenated with whatever the value of the variable `$abc` is.

Comment: Thanks William! So there is no way to use a string with $ in my .bashrc? The key would have to be changed, correct?

Comment: @JasonP, or just use single quotes instead of double quotes. `export my_key='123$abc'` would work fine. The mistake being made here has nothing to do with Python -- you could see the same problem if you ran `echo "$my_key"` in bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This worked also! Thank you, I toyed with this earlier but it probably did not work because I was not reloading my .bashrc settings in my code editor, thus reading in old .bashrc settings (just figured this out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape `$`.

```
my_key="123\$abc"
```

Comment: Worked! Appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to be of some help to you. If you find it useful, please accept the answer.

Comment: Accepted ✅ thanks again